# Redux saga called once, then the same saga is ignored

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a React JS app, which calls a Redux Saga in order to access a rest API resource. The idea is to call a resource with certain uuid and this call returns the next uuid for the next call. When the props change in React, the `componentDidUpdate` method launches the action that deploys the saga. It does fine for the first time, then the second call ignores the saga with no error and no warning. Here is what I have:

```
export class MyComp extends React.Component {
   ...
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevProps.uuid !== this.props.uuid) {
          this.props.actions.fetchData(this.props.uuid);
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

These are the actions:

```
export function fetchData(uuid) {
   return {
      type: FETCH_DATA_REQUEST,
      payload: { uuid }
   };
}

export function dataFetched(uuid, data) {
   return {
      type: DATA_FETCHED,
      payload: {uuid, data}
   };
}
```

and this is the saga:

```
export function * loadData({payload}) {
   try {
      const resp = yield call(request, URL, Object.assign({}, buildHeaders(), {method: 'get'}));
      yield put(dataFetched(resp.uuid, resp.data));
   } catch (error) {
      // handle the error
   }
}

...

export default function * defaultSaga () {
   ...
   yield takeLatest (FETCH_DATA_REQUEST, loadData);
}
```

I've been using React and Redux Sagas for a while, and this is the very first time it happens to me. I went into the Redux Sagas documentation and found nothing related to this.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3, Chromiun, React 16.6.3, Redux Sagas 0.16.2... I wonder what am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the saga fires? drop console.log before try

Comment: @kinduser, the saga fires the first time... then it is ignored with no error and no warning...

Comment: Does componentDidUpdate fire? If so - try replacing `takeLatest` with `takeEvery`

Comment: it keeps the same with `takeEvery` instead of `takeLatest`

Comment: Can you show the reducer that updates `uuid` in store?